# ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN utilizando AFTER en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

Hola buenos días comunidad, estoy intentando agregar una columna a una tabla en SQL Server utilizando la clausula AFTER pero me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrían orientar en como debería de ejecutar adecuadamente esta consulta.

La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Te faltaría si es Null o Not Null después de Int

Comment: @Bicho Lo acabo de hacer pero me marca el mismo error

Comment: Puedes agregar la estructura de tu tabla?

Comment: @Bicho Ya he agregado la estructura de la tabla amigo

Answer (score 1):

En SQL Server no existe el AFTER al usar `ALTER TABLE ADD columna`. Por eso siempre te mostrará error.

Esto es por diseño, ya que el órden de las columnas debería ser intrascendente según la teoría de base de datos. Sólo sirve para ahorrar código al momento de utilizar la tabla.

Comment: Hola @Luis, esto quiere decir que puedo agregar la columna sin utilizar After y al momento de hacer la carga de información automáticamente se almacenará en la columna que le corresponde sin importar el orden?

Comment: No, eso quiere decir que al hacer la carga de información tienes que especificar el órden de las columnas de origen y como se relacionan con las columnas de destino.